# Ubuntu 14.04 lts slow boot, several minutes

Tags: 14.04, boot

I use ubuntu 14.04 in a laptop hp pavillion (4Gb ram), in dual boot with Windows 10.
Lately I've realised that after I select ubuntu on grub it takes several minutes to start. I'd like some tips about fixing this problem, since I'm not an expert of ubuntu.

This is the bootchart
[bootchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6k6U.jpg)

From dmesg the most suspicious point is this

```
[   21.819255] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device

[   21.819332] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48

[   21.819366] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device

[   21.819368] radeon 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier

[   21.828388] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.40.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0

[  149.519775] init: failsafe main process (735) killed by TERM signal

[  150.838440] audit_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed

[  150.838444] audit: type=1400 audit(1477752769.503:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=890 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

a delay of more than 100 seconds.

If someone could give me some advice I'll be very grateful

Comment: You might add the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` to your question. Cheers, Al

Comment: it seems that systemd-analyze is not present in 14.04